# Get current bash epoch

Tags: linux, bash, epoch

So I made a bash script to ssh onto lots of computers and play a sound all at once.
I'm running into issues when trying to sync them though.
My approach is:

```
Get current epoch on my computer,
Add a 20 second delay (to allow for transfer times) [target_epoch]
connect to & send .wav files to each computer in parallel. 
Run a few lines of bash on each computer:
    sync time with google, 
    get bot epoch
    calc how long to sleep based off: target_epoch - bot_epoch
    sleep and then play .wav file
```

Getting my computer epoch with:

```
current_epoch=$(date +%s.%N)
target_epoch=$(echo "$current_epoch + 20"|bc)
```

Code running on each remote computer:

```
sudo date -s '$(wget --method=HEAD -qSO- --max-redirect=0 google.com 2>&1 | sed -n 's/^ *Date: *//p')';\
bot_current_epoch=$(date +%s.%N);\
echo 'Current epoch: ' ${bot_current_epoch};\
echo 'Target epoch:  ' ${target_epoch};\
amixer set 'Master' ${volume}% 1> /dev/null;\
echo 'Sleep until:${target_epoch} time now:  ${bot_current_epoch}' ;\
echo 'Sleep for: '$(echo "$target_epoch - $bot_current_epoch"|bc);\
sleep $(echo "$target_epoch - $bot_current_epoch"|bc);\
aplay /tmp/${wavFile} 2> /dev/null;"
```

(oh, I'm saving that code as a string and then passing it via ssh to the remote computer)

the issue I have is that it's not setting the bot_current_epoch variable

originally I had `bot_current_epoch` use the same name as `current_epoch` and so it didn't update the current epoch time so all bots just waited for the 20-second delay and didn't actually sync up.  When I changed the var to bot_current_epoch it failled and I noticed that `bot_current_epoch=$(date +%s.%N);\`  wasn't actually updating the var

Comment: why not instead wait for the files to transfer, instead of waiting 20 seconds? `I made a bash script to ssh` Did you consider ansible?

Comment: I hadn't thought of waiting for the transfer to complete. Do you have an example? So you would transfer all the files in parallel, then `wait` (until all background processes are finished). then send the play command? An issue with that would be that you are reestablishing a remote connection after transferring the files, so the bots would still not really be synced up (slight changes in connection times when sending the `play` cmd)

Comment: `So you would transfer all the files in parallel, then wait` Why not use `parallel` or `xargs` (or ansible) to manage background processes for you? I would rather consider bash scripting on the end. `An issue with that would be that you are reestablishing` Use ControlMaster in ssh settings to reuse connection. There are odd \ on the end of each line in your script. It's not like no one has done it before you, the general solution is ansible, puppet or other configuration management tool.

Comment: I dont see how that would help though as the base issue with the syncing up is difference in network connections when sending the wav files. EX, if computer A takes 5 seconds, B 9, and C13; then each bot will start playing the sound 4 seconds after the last one....

Comment: You are specifying the requirements. You want them synchronized (ansible execution strategy "linear") or all run in parallel ("free" execution strategy in ansible)? How do you "sync files"? Why in your script do you pass `date -s` with a single quoted argument? And why use `date -s` at all, and not timesyncd or ntpd? I run away.

Comment: I am using `rsync` to send the wav files to remote computers. the `date -s '$wget--.....` stuff is just how i was syncing the time with google. I'm using that because that is what I found when googling how to sync time with google lol

Comment: Your last command block `sudo date -s '$(wget ...` has syntax errors. You can already see on the syntax highlighting here, that the `'` is *closed* at `sed -n '`. But even if it wasn't, having `$()` inside a single quoted string at that place seems suspicious. Try to fix those syntax errors. https://www.shellcheck.net/ can help you with that and even more.

Comment: Escaping code to run on a remote server is something you should have the shell do for you -- doing it by hand is _very_ error-prone even for experts. The easy way is to write a shell function with the code you want to remotely run; after you do that, `"$(declare -f the_function_name); the_function_name"` evaluates to a string that runs that code inside the function named, ready to pass to ssh. (If you need to pass variables over ssh, use `declare -p` to serialize them the same way).

Comment: Indeed, I'm tempted to argue that this question is either too broad to be topical (it doesn't specify a single narrow, specific bug but instead gives us a big mess of buggy code), or duplicative (of existing questions about how to reliably run arbitrary code over ssh, which are already answered with the above technique).

Comment: _saving that code as a string and then passing it via ssh to the remote computer_ : Not a good idea. Too error prone. To rule out the possibility that stringification causes trouble, store the code as a script which is accessible on the remote system and execute this script.

Comment: Hint of the day: `$EPOCHSECONDS`.